# Is there a better Postgres query to fetch top first rows in a group?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have four tables foo, bar, baz, and qux

foo:

[image: foo]

bar:

[image: bar]

baz:

[image: baz]

qux:

[image: qux]

I'm looking for an output like:

[image: output]

---

I've written this query with minimal joins but I don't know of a way to optimize it.
There's going to be 100k+ records in bar. I just need the first row from **bar** whose column **bar1** matches with **foo2** in **foo**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo_pk)
    foo_pk,
    foo1,
    qux1,
    bar_str.r1,
    bar_str.r2,
    bar_str.r3,
    (
        SELECT
            string_agg(CONCAT_WS(' ', baz_pk, baz2, baz3), ' | ')
        FROM
            baz
        WHERE
            baz1 = foo_pk
        GROUP BY
            baz1
    )
FROM
    foo
    JOIN qux ON qux_pk = foo2
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            RIGHT(bar3, 1) AS r1,
            RIGHT(bar3, 2) AS r2,
            RIGHT(bar3, 3) AS r3,
            bar1
        FROM
            bar
        ORDER BY
            bar1,
            bar2
    ) AS bar_str ON bar_str.bar1 = foo2
ORDER BY foo_pk
```

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=90df0e18006549caaef70bb6a23f5be3)

I'm running Postgres v11.9  btw.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Ideally combined with a short [DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14).

Comment: Please share explain analyze buffers output for us to understand your data distribution and current execution plan.